# WordPress Rewrite Rule to exclude specific slug

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule in my `functions.php` which is working just fine.

```
function custom_offers_rewrite() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^offers/([a-z-_]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=1948&offer_restaurant=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

This looks for anything like `/offers/my-custom-path` and then loads in a specific page template / ID (page_id=1948). This template displays some custom things and we're all good.

Whilst that's fine, I have a literal page on the URL path, `/offers/all` and I would like to exclude this from the rewrite rule.

Is this possible at all?

So, in other words, if we hit `/offers/all`, just ignore the rule and carry on as normal. If anything else, do the rule as it currently works.

I suppose it needs some adjustment to the Regex, but I'm barely any good at pattern matching.

Help and advice appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out eventually.

Working code that will ignore `/offers/all` but work with everything else:

```
function custom_offers_rewrite() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^offers/(?!all)([a-z-_]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=1948&offer_restaurant=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

The key part, being the addition of `(?!all)` into the Regex.

Hope this manages to help someone else.

**Important**: Remember to save the permalinks in WordPress in order to flush the rewrite cache!

Comment: what if I have to exclude multiple slugs?